# access files code of big commerce Optimized one-page checkout (Early access)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce, stencils

I am using big commerce classic next store, however, I have to use the Optimized one-page check out: early access for check out I want to add their custom fields and made some changes into text but I cannot find the file of that checkout page. I have also checked the stencil theme there is not any access to this page so please I how I can edit this page files guide me.

here is a screenshot of the page

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Where is your code

Comment: Lol! I didn't found coded file of that page that's why I am asking the question here!

Answer (score 0):

There are only two options for making changes to optimized checkout as the template files aren't accessible today.

1) You can inject javascript into checkout seen [here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/checkout-injection).
2) You can style it as seen [here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/optimized-checkout-customization).

For any more direct customization, BigCommerce will be releasing new features before the end of the year to support this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in those files on the header of check out we can edit even if tried to make changes with javascript css it's not accepting it.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how it isn't accepting it?

Comment: if you go to our checkout.html page there is an option for editing header logo only but whole file code is not there that's why it's not accepting the js and css code because the js and css file not found classes.